# I'm trying to set a value in a QButtonGroup using .setId but I get a Type Error

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, typeerror

Hey I'm trying to code a GUI for a planetary simulator. I'm using PyQt5 and using a QComboBox. I know the values of a comboBox use negative numbers eg. -2 for the first box but when I try to set it as -2, I get a TypeError.

This is the button group colours:

```
self.colors = QButtonGroup()
    self.blue = QCheckBox("Blue")
    self.red = QCheckBox("Red")
    self.yellow = QCheckBox("Yellow")
    self.green = QCheckBox("Green")
    self.orange = QCheckBox("Orange")
    self.purple = QCheckBox("Purple")
    self.pink = QCheckBox("Pink")
    self.white = QCheckBox("White")
    self.colors.addButton(self.blue)
    self.colors.addButton(self.red)
    self.colors.addButton(self.yellow)
    self.colors.addButton(self.green)
    self.colors.addButton(self.orange)
    self.colors.addButton(self.purple)
    self.colors.addButton(self.pink)
    self.colors.addButton(self.white)
```

This is how I try to set it:

```
`if planet == "Planet 1":
    self.slider1.setValue(planets.p1.radius)
    self.colors.setId(planets.p1.colour)'
```

Obviously the value of `planets.p1.colour` is an integer (eg. If i want the planet to be blue the value will be -2 which will correspond to a colour in the Planet class.)

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: setId(self, QAbstractButton, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `self.colors.button(planets.p1.colour).setChecked(True)`

Comment: @ekhumoro that doesnt seem to work, I now get the error "TypeError: button(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method' "

Comment: Well then that means `planets.p1.colour` is a method, and not an attribute containing an integer as you claim in your question. I suggest you check the code that sets the planet colour to make sure it really is an integer.